# SPWeb.ContentTypes["Document Set"] returns Null?

Tags: 2013, document-set, community-site

I am writing code for creating `DocumentSets` dynamically in one of my Document libraries in a SP2013 Community site.

```
SPContentType docSetCT = web.ContentTypes["Document Set"];
```

The above line always returns `Null` and in turn the next line of codes error out.

I have activated the `Document Set` feature at the site collection level.
The Community site is created by the same code, prior to the code line in concern.
The Document Library is also created in the same code, prior to the code line in concern.

I am able to get the object `SPContentType docSetCT`, if i use `AvailableContentTypes["Document Set"]` instead of `ContentTypes["Document Set"]`. But, then i receive another error while creating the DocumentSet at following line of code.

```
docSet = DocumentSet.Create(docLibrary, docTitle, docSetCT.Id, docSetProperties);
```

I receive following error,

> The content type "Folder" at "/" is sealed.
>
> at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.Update(Boolean
>   updateChildren, Boolean ignoreSealedOrReadOnly, Boolean
>   throwOnSealedOrReadOnly, IList`1 exceptions)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.ProvisionCTEventReceivers(SPContentType
>   contentType)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.Provision(Boolean
>   bProvisionDefaultContent, SPLongOperationState longOperationState)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.Create(SPFolder
>   parentFolder, String name, SPContentTypeId ctid, Hashtable properties,
>   Boolean bProvisionDefaultContent, SPUser user, SPLongOperationState
>   longOperationState)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet.Create(SPFolder
>   parentFolder, String name, SPContentTypeId ctid, Hashtable properties,
>   Boolean bProvisionDefaultContent)    at
>   JiveContentMigration.JiveContentMigrationWebpart.JiveContentMigrationWebpartUserControl.uploadDocumentToLibrary(SPWeb
>   web, String docLibraryName, String folderName, String subFolderName,
>   String jiveDocumentSummary, String jiveDocumentBodyText, DateTime
>   createdOn, String docTitle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable content types and add the Document Set content type for this to work.

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            {
                using (SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
                {

                    // Get a content type.
                    SPContentType ct = site.AvailableContentTypes["Financial Document"];
   if (ct != null)
                    {

                        SPList list = site.Lists["Shared Documents"]; /
                        list.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
                        list.ContentTypes.Add(ct);

                        SPContentType[] orderedContentTypes = new SPContentType[list.ContentTypes.Count];

                        list .EnableFolderCreation = false;
                        list .Update();

                        SPFolder rootFolder = list .RootFolder;
                        SPContentTypeCollection oContentTypes = list.ContentTypes;

                        int CTCount = 0;
                        foreach (SPContentType oContentType in oContentTypes)
                        {                        
                            orderedContentTypes[CTCount] = oContentType;
                            CTCount++;

                         }
                       rootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = orderedContentTypes;
                       rootFolder.Update();
                     }
                 }
               }
```

http://alancejacob.blogspot.com/2012/09/programically-add-site-content-type-and.html

Comment: I think i was missing to add the `Document Set` content type to my Library, before adding the Document Set. Thanks for sending me in the right direction.....Will mark this as answer after i get it working.

Comment: Awesome...let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SharePoint-2010-Creating-41d2aa7a/sourcecode?fileId=49432&pathId=648538632

```
protected void createDocSetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        //Get the Shared Documents document library 
        SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web; 
        SPDocumentLibrary sharedDocsLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)currentWeb.Lists["Shared Documents"]; 
        //You can use a hashtable to populate properties of the document set 
        Hashtable docsetProperties = new Hashtable(); 
        docsetProperties.Add("Name", nameTextbox.Text); 
        docsetProperties.Add("Description", descriptionTextbox.Text); 
        //Create the document set 
        try 
        { 
            DocumentSet newDocSet = DocumentSet.Create(sharedDocsLib.RootFolder, 
                nameTextbox.Text, sharedDocsLib.ContentTypes["Document Set"].Id, 
                docsetProperties, true); 
            resultLabel.Text = "Document set created"; 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            resultLabel.Text = "An error occurred: " + ex.Message; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Getting `Object reference not set to a instance of an object.` error at `DocumentSet newDocSet = DocumentSet.Create(sharedDocsLib.RootFolder, nameTextbox.Text, sharedDocsLib.ContentTypes["Document Set"].Id, docsetProperties, true); `

Comment: Make sure to replace or set values to: nameTextbox.Text and descriptionTextbox.Text

You'll need to replace "Shared Documents" with the name of your library.

Comment: Yes, i did that. While debugging the code, i can see the library object is created for my Library and the values for Name and Description are hard-coded.

Comment: You think this line could be the problem?

    sharedDocsLib.ContentTypes["Document Set"].Id

Comment: Yes, i think so. As it was in my original code. I don't think we did anything different.

Comment: When you go to your library settings, do you see Document Sets listed under content types?

Comment: No, its not. As the document library is created in this code only.

Comment: I think that's the problem then. Going to post a 2nd answer. Just a sec.